# Why doesn't the compiler choose the other overload when I remove template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm trying to write C++ code to understand whether some class has a default constructor or not (without C++20 concepts). The following code works just fine.

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
    C() = delete;
};

template<typename T>
struct HasDefaultConstructor {
    template<typename U>
    static auto test(int) -> decltype(U(), std::true_type{});

    template<typename U>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
};

int main() {
    bool a = HasDefaultConstructor<C>::value;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However when I change the test functions to the ones below and use `decltype(test(0))::value` I get a compilation error.

```
    static auto test(int) -> decltype(T(), std::true_type{});
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
```

The error says that `C::C()` is a deleted function. I'm wondering why doesn't the compiler complain when it's a templated version and why doesn't it choose the other version of `test`(`test(...)`) when the version with `int` fails to compile? Could you please explain how SFINAE works here?

Comment: **The SFINAE applies only on templates**. When instancing a template, if its declaration is not valid, it doesn't exist. On your second try, the functions are not template, so SFINAE doesn't apply, the functions like any function **must** be valid. Since C++20, we have requirements, and requirements can by applied to non template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering why doesn't the compiler complain when it's a templated version and why doesn't it choose the other version of `test`(`test(...)`) when the version with `int` fails to compile?

In order to work the SFINAE, the template parameter must be from the SFINAE'ed function template overloads.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

> This rule applies during overload resolution of **function templates**: When substituting the explicitly specified or **deduced type for the template parameter fails**, the specialization is discarded from the overload set instead of causing a compile error.

At your second case, they are not any more function templates rather members using the class template parameter for defining their trailing return types.

```
template<typename T>
struct HasDefaultConstructor
{
   // following are not function templates!!
   static auto test(int) -> decltype(T(), std::true_type{});
   static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
   // ....
};
```

i.e. You are using the template parameter type `T` directly from the class template, instead of the template parameter of the functions (i.e. `U`). This changes the behavior because the type `T` is resolved during the substitution stage, even if the expression `T()` is not evaluated.

The problem is that the failing substitution is happening in the return type of the function templates, which is not part of the immediate context for SFINAE. As a result, the compiler reports an error instead of applying SFINAE and selecting the second overload.